# Google Adwords Conversion Tracking: Missing <noscript> tag

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I am trying to implement the Google AdWords Conversion Tracking on a "Thank you" page after form submission. I am using the Google Tag Assistant in Chrome to test my tags.

Here is my code. Of course the values for the conversion_label and conversion_id are changed to the values given by Google.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    /* <![CDATA[ */
         var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
         var google_conversion_language = "en";
         var google_conversion_format = "2";
         var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";     
        var google_conversion_label = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";     
        var google_remarketing_only = false;     
        var google_conversion_value = 0;
    /* ]]> */     
</script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">     
</script>     
<noscript>
    <div style="display: inline">
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/123456789/?label=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>     
    </div>
</noscript>
```

However, I get this error when checking the tag in Google Tag Assistant: `Missing <noscript> tag.`

The `<noscript>` tag is there, and present when I go into the source code. Yet I am still getting this error. I tried putting that `<noscript>` tag in many places, without any luck.
The manual doesn't give any further information on this error.

Also, does this affect the tracking conversion ?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try to write the noscript tag on above the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

The noscript bit is only required for browsers which do not have javascript enabled (this is a very small number of users these days) - if the browser has javascript enabled it will execute the javascript as normal.

Sometimes the tag assistant gets confused though (particularly if there are DOM or script errors elsewhere on the page it is checking) - that snippet you pasted looks ok to me, and a test in jsbin.com suggests everything is fine.